# Put text into second input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Lets say i have two input fields:

```
<input id="1"  value="A part of this text is hidden">
<input id="2">
```

How can i check with jquery if the input text is longer than the input width, for example:

```
 <input id="1" value="A part of this text is hidden">
```

`input` has a width of `60px`.

and the text `A part of this text is hidden` a width of lets say `100px`.

**Means that  `40px` of the text is hidden.**

How can i check if text is hidden and automaticly put this text in the second input, so that at the end my html would look like this:

```
<input id="1"  value="A part of">
<input id="2" value="this text is hidden">
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Np3Lw/

Comment: What is the point of doing this?

Comment: Is there a logical data reason to split the input?  Have you considered using a textarea?

Comment: If the text is splitted than how do you enter text?

Comment: The thing is that the distances between my inputs, in total i have 5, are not the same so that i cannot use a textaera with a fixed line height!

Comment: How much effort are you willing to spend on this? I've done something like that in the past, but it involved creating a non-visible `div` with the same font, adding the text in there one word at a time until the `div` grows in height. At that point you know how much text you can fit in a single line in the `div`, so also how much text you can fit in a single `input` of the same width. If there is no simpler way this may work, but it "somewhat non-trivial".

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - It's time to use `ctx.measureText` to get the exact width of text.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: that's on `Canvas` only, isn't it? But it might indeed save the whole "add words/letters until the div grows" logic.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yea not only that, the code would be much cleaner and easier than understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I got a solution: 
JS :

```
 var str = $("#1").val(); //Get the first input value.

 if (str.length < 9) { //Check the length.
     alert("Size fits input field :" + str);
 } else {
     //To get the remaining characters.
     newstr = str.substr(10, str.length);
     $("#2").val(newstr); //Append to the second input field.
 }
```

**[DEMO HERE >>](http://jsfiddle.net/Np3Lw/2/)**

Comment: NOTE: This will only work if you have a fixed-width font and figure out exactly how many characters the field can take, before hiding characters (tested in different browsers, of course ;) ).  Variable width fonts will leave you with unpredictable results . . . e.g., "abcdefg" may fit just perfectly, but "iiiiiii" may leave extra "unused" space in the input, and "WWWWWWW" may have some of the text go past the edge of the input.